# XNA: Conditional Draw

Tags: button, xna

Im making a game on WP7. I have added a button in it. what i want to do is that whenever i touch the button, the button sprite should change its frame from 0 to 1 (0 being the button-up frame and 1 being the button-pressed frame). i have added the sprite sheet for the button which contains two frames only. the size is also okay.

to summarize, i want to do this:

1) when touch the button
2) button-pressed frame should be drawn and come back to original frame after 1 or 2 sec. (just like it happens in every game with buttons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds more like a design issue then an implementation issue.  Basically, you need an idea getting you started.  I'm not too familiar with WP7 specifically, but I'll show you the basic design you could use; with some sudo code you can fill in later.

```
class Button
{
    private Point CellSize;
    public Point Position {get; set;}

    private Texture2D buttonSheet;

    public Button (Texture2D texture, Point CellSize)
    {
        this.buttonSheet = texture;
        this.CellSize = CellSize;
    }

    public bool isPressed {get; private set;}

    public void Update (bool isPressed)
    {
        this.isPressed = isPressed;
    }

    public void Draw (SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        Rectangle Source = new Rectangle (0,0,CellSize.X,CellSize.Y);
        if (this.isPressed)
            Source = new Rectangle (CellSize.X * 1, CellSize.Y * 1, CellSize.X, CellSize.Y);
        sb.Draw (this.buttonSheet, new Rectangle(this.Position.X,this.Position.Y,CellSize.X,CellSize.Y), Source, Color.White);
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
class Game1
{
    Button Start = new Button(new Texture2D() /*load and include your texture here*/, new Point (100, 50) /* 100 wide, 50 tall cells */);
    public Update (GameTime gt)
    {
        bool clicked = false /* Put code here to check if the button is pressed */;
        Start.Update(clicked);
    }

    public Draw (SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        Start.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

(note haven't tested this code)
Hope that helps you get started, feel free to elaborate if you want more info on a specific part.
Max